# how to replacle multiple continuous string with single string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string as `'kj,,,,,,,,,sdkdsd,das,das,,,,dasdasd,,,,,ad'`

and now I want to replace multiple `commas` with single
as

`'kj,sdkdsd,das,das,sdasd,ad'`

note: 
with best performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
DECLARE @mystring VARCHAR(50) = 'kj,,,,,,,,,sdkdsd,das,das,,,,dasdasd,,,,,ad'

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@mystring, ',', '{}'), '}{', ''), '{}', ',')
```

**Output:** `kj,sdkdsd,das,das,dasdasd,ad`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
declare @str varchar(100)='kj,,,,,,,,,sdkdsd,das,das,,,,dasdasd,,,,,ad'

declare @strBefore varchar(100)=''
WHILE @strBefore<>@str BEGIN
  SET @strBefore=@str
  SET @str=REPLACE(@str,',,',',')
END
print @str
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `WHILE` loop:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(200) = 'kj,,,,,,,,,sdkdsd,das,das,,,,dasdasd,,,,,ad'

WHILE @s LIKE '%,,%'
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, ',,', ',')

SELECT  @s
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use CLR RegEx replace. Read more here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

and then call it:

```
SELECT dbo.RegExReplace('kj,,,,,,,,,sdkdsd,das,das,,,,dasdasd,,,,,ad', ',{2,}', ',')
```

Comment: CLR is a bit overkill for something so simple.

Comment: It would be overkill for something like this, but this can be used in future development. And on top of that, you wouldn't have to worry about other complex replaces later.